# Url parameter to servlet doGet()

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm working on my first web application. I am sending email with an url in it:

```
http://localhost:8080/HotelP/requeteSuccesO.jsp?hotelId=hampton&city=Montreal
```

When clicking on the link, requeteSuccesO.jsp displays the hotelId and city parameters:

```
out.println("<b>Hotel:</b> "+request.getParameter("hotelId")+"</br>");
out.println("<b>City:</b> "+request.getParameter("city")+"</br>");
```

Then the user can accept by clicking on a button:

```
<form method="get" action="acceptOffer">
<input type="submit" value="Accept" class="sanslabel">
```

acceptOffer is mapped to a servlet DecisionPage.java, and by clicking on that button it's calling the doGet() method.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("in do get DecisionPage, hotelId is "+request.getParameter("hotelId"));
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE_PAIEMENT ).forward( request, response );
}
```

The parameter hotelId received by the doGet function is null, but I am expecting it to be the value found in the url (in our case, "hampton")

Can anyone tell me why I get null and not "hampton" ?

Comment: How do you call your servlet through that link? you'd better to post the JSP code as well where you call your servlet  DecisionPage.java. And also post any error message if you have when you open your browser's developer console.

Comment: The servlet is called by <form method="get" action="acceptOffer">
acceptOffer is mapped to DecisionPage.java in web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a form and submit that form to some action, it will only create request parameters for the `fields` you have defined in your form.

So, while you run the application with mentioned URL, it would contain those parameters and will be avilable to your `jsp` but if you don't include them in your form it won't be available to `servlet` when you submit the form.

So, you need to include those parameters to some `hidden` fields if you don't won't to show them to user.

Example:

```
<form method="get" action="acceptOffer">
    <input type="hidden" name="hotelId" value="<%= request.getParameter(\"hotelId\")" %> />   <---- this field will create a new parameter with name as hotelId
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<%= request.getParameter(\"city\") %>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Accept" class="sanslabel">
</form>
```

So, now as we made a new fields `hotelId` and `city` they will be sent to your servlet `acceptOffer` and then you'll be able to access them with request parameter as below:

`request.getParameter("hotelId")`

Comment: A fat -1 for not covering the gaping XSS hole, let alone leaving a small hint to wake up the OP.

Comment: @BalusC: I am sorry but even I am not aware of thing you mentioned. It would be better if you could edit the answer and cover it. Even I would get some idea as well from that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include those paramters in the form itself because the scope of the paramters is request scope. Something like this

```
 <form method="get" action="acceptOffer">
<input type="text" name="hotelId" value=assign the value from request here/>
<input type="submit" value="Accept" class="sanslabel">
</form>
```